# Fabric - App could not be install error iOS

Tags: google-fabric

I have recently updated Fabric and I am getting an issue where users can no longer install the beta apps I send out. I keep getting the error saying - app could not be installed at this time. Has anyone encountered this issue since updating Fabric? Up until the update, I have had no issues sending out beta builds.

**Edit**: I just tried installing old version of app sent out with old fabric, it installed fine and works. I then get an alert saying there is a new version you can update to (the one I sen out recently), when it finishes installing that, it then shows error saying could not be installed again.

**Edit 2** Confirmed it is an issue with updated Fabric. My have a git branch that was last updated on Monday, this was prior to the Fabric update. So I tested on that branch, archived app, sent out, can download just fine. I then updated Fabric, and sent out again, then I got the error message saying unable to download app.

Comment: It would be helpful also to check for valid certificate and/or provisioning profile which is being used by your app.

Comment: Cert and profiles are all valid. If they were not valid, I would get a warning on Fabric when sending out to users saying their device has not been added. Also if you see my edit 2, you can see the profiles are definitely ok as I sent out a build, worked fine, I then updated Fabric, then tried again, then the issue occurred, so it is not a profile issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem. It seems installing the new Fabric through the manual install process is the problem. I had installed Fabric following these instructions

https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/manual-install

After trying multiple reinstalls without any success, I tried to install the new Fabric via Cocoapods and now it seems to work fine. Hope this helps anyone else having the same issue